# Docusaurus: how to add custom css

Tags: css, node.js, docusaurus

I am trying to use `academicons` (see [1](https://jpswalsh.github.io/academicons/)) with docusaurus. These are icons that would be relevant for academic pages, such as google scholar, and overleaf icons.

The academicons instructions say I should add the following to the header of my html document;

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/jpswalsh/academicons@1/css/academicons.min.css">
```

However, I am unsure how to add this to docusaurus. I know I can add a `custom.css` file under `src/css/custom.css`, add refer it in `presets.theme.cusomCss` in `docusaurus.config.js`, but that is a reference to a local file. How do I add an online css?

Answer (score 0):

use the `stylesheets` configuration in `docusaurus.config.ts`:

```js
export default {
  stylesheets: [
    // String format.
    'https://docusaurus.io/style.css',
    // Object format.
    {
      href: 'https://docusaurus.io/style2.css',
    },
  ],
};
```

Read more from [docusaurus docs](https://docusaurus.io/docs/api/docusaurus-config#stylesheets).

Answer (score -1):

Open your Docusaurus project folder in a code editor.

Navigate to the docusaurus.config.js file, which is in the root directory of your project.

Inside the docusaurus.config.js, look for the presets section. Under presets, there should be a @docusaurus/preset-classic object. Within that object, there's likely a theme section.

In the theme section, you can add a customCss property and set it as an array. This property allows you to specify the URL of an external CSS file that you want to include in your Docusaurus site.

Here's an example of how to add the academicons CSS link:

```
module.exports = {
  // ...
  presets: [
    [
      '@docusaurus/preset-classic',
      {
        theme: {
          customCss: [
            'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/jpswalsh/academicons@1/css/academicons.min.css',
            // Add more external CSS links if needed
          ],
        },
      },
    ],
  ],
  // ...
};
```

Save the changes to docusaurus.config.js.

Run the development server for Docusaurus again using npm run start or yarn start, and the academicons CSS should be included in your Docusaurus project. if not you should include it .

By adding the external CSS link to the customCss property, you can reference online CSS files in Docusaurus. This is especially useful for cases like yours when you need to include academicons or other external libraries.

Comment: Thank you. So, at the moment I have:

```presets: [['classic', ({ <some stuff here>, theme: { customCss: require.resolve('./src/css/custom.css'), 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/jpswalsh/academicons@1/css/academicons.min.css',]}})]]```

However, I get 

```Cannot find module '/Users/<user name>/code/my-website/https:/cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/jpswalsh/academicons@1/css/academicons.min.css'```

Comment: You cannot directly add an online CSS link like https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/jpswalsh/academicons@1/css/academicons.min.css to the customCss property in docusaurus.config.js.

Comment: But isn't that what you suggested above?